# Guardar filas de excel en datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

```
   A         B           C
1 COLUMN1   COLUMN1    COLUMN3
2 XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   
3 XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   
4 XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   
5 XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX    XXXXXXX
```

--

```
DataTable excelTable = new DataTable("ExcelFile");
DataTable original = GetDataTableExcel();

excelTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN1", typeof(string));
excelTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN2", typeof(string));
excelTable.Columns.Add("COLUMN3", typeof(string));

 foreach (DataRow item in original.Rows)
 {                
   DataRow temp = excelTable.NewRow();
       if (item[2] == "COLUMN1")
       {
        //
         if (item[3] == "COLUMN2")
          {
           //
            if (item[4] == "COLUMN3")
            { 

            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Como le puedo hacer para que vaya recorriendo las filas y que se guarden en DataRow temp, es decir donde encuentre Column1, guarde lo que esta en la fila 2, y asi con la Column2 y 3, y que para la siguiente vuelta guarde lo que esta en la fila 3 de las tres `Columns` y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: porque quieres que se guarden los datos a partir de la fila 2?

Comment: Porque la primera fila son los titulos de la columna.

Answer (score 0):

Entonces aquí te pongo una opción, usando la librería de LinqToExcel.
Primero tienes que hacer una clase con los datos de las columnas de la tabla que esta en tu hoja de excel, asi como aqui;

```
    [ExcelColumn("COLUMN1")] //Nombre de la columna de la tabla de excel
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    [ExcelColumn("COLUMN2")]
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    [ExcelColumn("COLUMN3")]
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
```

y despues en tu formulario o clase donde cargas el Excel pones este codigo;

```
OpenFileDialog openExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label2.Text = openExcel.FileName;
            try
            {
                string rutaE = label2.Text;
                var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(rutaE);//cargas la ruta del documento
                var res = (from row in book.Worksheet("Hoja1")
                           let item = new Programa //aqui recorres los datos
                           {
                               Column1 = row[0].Cast<String>(),
                               Column2 = row[1].Cast<String>(),
                               Column3 = row[2].Cast<String>(),
                           }
                           select item).ToList();
                book.Dispose();
                DataTable.DataSource = res;//Cargarmos los campos de excel al DataTable
```